# Is kafka 2.0.0 a stable version that can be used for production?

Tags: apache-kafka, release, production-environment

I have to upgrade Kafka from 0.10.0 to 2.0.0 for a production system. Is it a stable release? Also, is there a concept of GA, RC, and M2 for Kafka releases?

Comment: 2.0.0 is the latest release. The current stable version is 2.0.0.

Comment: Most companies would prefer to stay one back on 1.1.x patch release though. There's also lots of other changes to take into account than only the version, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes Kafka 2.0.0 is a stable release and it can be used in production.

Apache Kafka also uses Release Candidates before releasing new stable versions. For example 2.0.0 went through 3 RCs before reaching [GA](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-dev/201807.mbox/%3CCAOJcB3-fryH23F4rirtdP%2B2e6sBqDL-qEQB%2B60p6ueOoM52Nvw%40mail.gmail.com%3E). ([RC0](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-dev/201806.mbox/%3CCAOJcB3_fYz%2BtM-bC9SsWV82vPc2DEprdP1wGEEOb2G20etceuw%40mail.gmail.com%3E), [RC1](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-dev/201806.mbox/%3CCAOJcB39GdTWOaK4qysvyPyGU8Ldm82t_TA364x1MP8a8OAod6A%40mail.gmail.com%3E), [RC2](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-dev/201807.mbox/%3CCAOJcB39QsmyOoZo4OidxSed5p-EHbFNS%3Dc-BBvTX3Lw2gfOF5w%40mail.gmail.com%3E)).

Apache Kafka however does not use Milestone Releases. A [Timed-based release plan](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Time+Based+Release+Plan) was voted by the community and is used to produce regular GA (production ready) releases.

Comment: Is kafka 2.2.X stable, as i need it for my project for the real time data.

Comment: Yes, all Kafka releases are stable